# Calling angular services globally

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of services which represent a backend logic, that is called by different angular controllers.

During development however I want to call these services directly, in order to test them in isolation, from the browser Javascript console.
How this can be done?

Say there is

```
app.service('service1', function() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        return "Hello"
    };
});
```

Now from Javascript console,

```
app.somethingToGetService('service1').sayHello()
```

?

Comment: To test your service, you should write a unit test. Not call them from the JavaScript console.

Comment: this use case is rare but you can still get it from $injector: `$injector.get('service1').sayHello();`: http://plnkr.co/edit/w5gjftCaBDIwm8J7LCE8?p=preview

Comment: But how to access $injector from the Javascript console (globally)?
Doing angular.injector() doesn't work.

Comment: Regarding the unit test comment, it is fine having a unit test, but doing exploratory testing of a backend logic (services) with a live real application is invaluable as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get injector for module and from it get service:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']).get('service1').sayHello()
```

Comment: Another way, which is supposedly more correct, since it doesn't re-instantiate the injector is:
    `angular.element(document).injector().get("service1").sayHello()`
(it assumes that ng-app is defined on body or html tag)